Substrate: Transfers Work Only for Genesis Accounts, Not New Wallets
’m working on a Substrate-based blockchain with ExistentialDeposit = 0. Transfers between accounts defined in the genesis configuration work perfectly. However, when transferring tokens to a newly created wallet (not in the genesis), the following happens:
The transfer logs events like balances.Withdraw, balances.Endowed, and balances.Transfer, indicating success.
The recipient account appears in system.account, but with:
free: 0
providers: 0
The tokens are deducted from the sender but do not show up in the recipient’s balance.
Transfers between genesis accounts work fine.
Newly created accounts exist in system.account after a transfer but remain inactive with zero balance. After transfer tokens gone from sender account.
Any help is appreciated!

Unless you have a specific use case, such as EVM, or you are knowledgeable about the process, I don’t recommend setting the ED to 0.

@AurevoirXavier I booked slot on calendly, but something wrong with the link. It is expired.

Sorry, I'm not available for meeting now.

Got the solution. ExistentialDeposit should not be 0. I just set it 1 (the smalest unit). And problem solved.
